# Default selection and reroute on changing selection for <select> in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I am having a few problems with this, but first let me outline what I am trying to do.

When the user first logs in , it takes them to `/home` which has a list of projects. Clicking on one of the projects will take them to `/project/84` if `84` is the number of that project. When they are routed to that URL there is a `<select>` with a list of projects (that were also listed on `/home`).

This is what should happen:

**1) The `<select>` should have a `value` equal to the name of the project selected. For example, if project `84` is called `Project 84`, it should already be displayed in the `<select>` even if there are 20 other other projects before and after it.**

**2) When the user selects a new `<option>` in `<select>`, it should automatically send a `GET` to the server to retrieve the information of the project they selected.**

So here is what I have so far:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class SelectProject extends Component {

    getProject() {
        // console.log('Working');
        this.setState({ 
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

    renderCurrentProjectName() {
        const { project_list } = this.props;

        if (!Project_list) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }

        return _(this.props.Project_list)
            .filter(c => c.project_id == this.props.Project_id)
            .map('project')
            .value();
    }

    renderProjectSelect() {
        return _.map(this.props.project_list, s => {
            return (
                <option key={s.project_id}>{s.project}</option>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className='panel panel-default'>
                <div className='panel-heading'>
                    <h4><strong>{this.renderCurrentProjectName()}</strong></h4>
                </div>

                <div className='panel-body'>
                    <select className='form-control' onChange={this.getProject()} value={this.renderCurrentProjectName()}>
                        {this.renderProjectSelect()}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        ); 
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        project_id: state.documents.project_id,
        project_list: state.documents.project_list
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SelectProject);
```

This just generates 1000 errors saying: `Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.`

This is caused by the `this.setState({ value: even.target.value })` so when I remove it I just get: `Warning: Failed form propType: You provided a 'value' prop to a form field without an 'onChange' handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use 'defaultValue'. Otherwise, set either 'onChange' or 'readOnly'. Check the render method of 'SelectProduct'.`

**This does accomplish `1)` though by selecting the name of the project in the `<select>`; however, you can't select anything else (haven't even gotten as sending the `GET`).**

`defaultValue` doesn't seem to do anything, at least it doesn't select the correct `<option>`.

Also have done the following which resulted in the same errors and behavior (i.e. it selects the correct `<option>`, but won't let you select anything else):

```
...
class SelectProject extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: this.renderCurrentProductName()
        };
    }

    getProject() {
        // console.log('Working');
        this.setState({ 
            value: event.target.value
        });
    }

                ...
                    <select className='form-control' onChange={this.getProject()} value={this.state.value}>
                        {this.renderProjectSelect()}
                    </select>
                ...
```

These are some of the SO questions I have been referencing.

[OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

[ReactJS: Select with default value from props without onChange event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749761/reactjs-select-with-default-value-from-props-without-onchange-event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you say why you are calling the functions in the on change?
Can you try passing the event to the function:

```
class SelectProject extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: this.renderCurrentProductName()
    };
}

getProject(event) {
    // console.log('Working');
    this.setState({ 
        value: event.target.value
    });
}

            ...
                <select className='form-control' onChange={this.getProject} value={this.state.value}>
                    {this.renderProjectSelect}
                </select>
            ...
```

Comment: Now I am getting: `Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`. Weird because in `getProject(event)` I can `console.log(event.target.value)` and get the `<option>` I have selected, but it doesn't apparently like the `this.setState({ value: event.target.value })`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const getProject = (event)=> {
    this.setState({ 
        value: event.target.value
    });
}
```

so try passing the event onChange, you are not passing the event as an argument so there is nothing to call target.value